# How can I set the width and hight and set up the scroll bar on a html or js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gist

So, I've inserted a **gist** from GitHub to my personal webpage.

And it's giving me this script to do it:

```js
<script src="https://gist.github.com/my_username/4e475964906b87e07ce66fddc29e39ee.js"></script>
```

Once I insert the script I get an expanded view of the whole gist.

It is very large, so what I want is to have it **500** by **400** with a scroll bar, so the user can check the entire code because below the code there is a dashboard.

I don't want them to scroll down through the entire webpage but only for the github gist.

How can I do this using **CSS**/**HTML**?

Comment: That is a `script` source from another url. That script must be creating an iframe element where you can look at the page from, so inspect the frame from the page and style its id or classname from css.

Comment: Please add the relevant code and your tries/ideas first